# How to check selected time whether match or not in shop time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

i am new to programmng and angularjs some one help me out for this.Here i need to check Given time is matched between shop open and close time.i get day from date and i have passed time .i have tried some code but it's not working .when i click button it should check with shop data and it show some message based on status.now i am getting invalid date line no 43.any one pls help me out below i given my condtions

```
Day: {
        "monday": "09:10AM - 06:30PM",
        "tuesday": "09:10AM - 12:00PM",
        "wednesday": "09:10AM - 06:30PM",
        "thursday": "09:10AM - 06:30PM",
        "friday": "09:10AM - 06:30PM",
        "saturday": "10:15AM - 04:15PM",
        "sunday": "10:15AM - 04:15PM"
      },
```

For example. 1.if i pass date(Wed Dec 02 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)/02/12/2015/Wednesday),and if i pass time 11:00am i need to check with shop day(which is mentioned above).passed day Wednesday and time 11.00am match between shop open and close time so i need to show alert shop is opened .

2.if i pass date(Thu Dec 03 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)/ 03/12/2015/ Thursday),and if i pass time 08:00pm i need to check with shop day(which is mentioned above).passed day Thursday and time 08:00pm does not match between shop open and close time so i need to show alert shop is closed or leave demo

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller("myCntrl", function($scope, $filter) {

    $scope.isOpen = function(dealerSchedule) {
 console.log(dealerSchedule);
      
   var udate='Wed Dec 02 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)';
   var now = new Date(udate);
   console.log(now);
   var times = dealerSchedule[Object.keys(dealerSchedule)[now.getDay() - 1]].replace(/(\d\d\:\d\d)(AM|PM)/g, '1/1/1900 $1 $2').split(" - ");
     
   //var nowTime = new Date('1/1/1900 ' + now.toLocaleTimeString(navigator.language, {
        //hour: '2-digit',
        //minute: '2-digit',
        //hour12: true
      //}));
   var ntime ='11:00am';
   var nowTime = new Date(ntime);
   console.log(nowTime);
      var response = (times == "Leave" ? "Leave" : (nowTime >= new Date(times[0]) && nowTime <= new Date(times[1]) ? "Open Now" : "Closed Now"));
     
   if(response =='Closed Now' || response =='Leave' )
   {
   alert('sorry shop closed');
   }else
   {
   alert('shop opened now');
   }
   
   
    };

 
    $scope.dealers = [{

       S_Email_id: "aditiya@gmail.com",
        S_Store: "samsung",
        status:"",
        Store_Name: "Adtiya Samsung Store",
        S_Services: "Regular Service,Software Faults,Hardware Faults",
        Store_long_description: "Undertake all kind of samsung mobiles",
        Store_short_description: "Undertake all kind of samsung mobiles",
      Day: {
        "monday": "09:10AM - 06:30PM",
        "tuesday": "09:10AM - 12:00PM",
        "wednesday": "09:10AM - 06:30PM",
        "thursday": "09:10AM - 06:30PM",
        "friday": "09:10AM - 06:30PM",
        "saturday": "10:15AM - 04:15PM",
        "sunday": "10:15AM - 04:15PM"
      },
    },  ]
    //var date = new Date();

    //$scope.hhmmsstt = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'hh:mm:ss a');
    //console.log($scope.hhmmsstt);
  })
//]]>
```

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.1.1/angular.min.js'></script>
  
  
  
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCntrl">
    <label>Search on Label</label>
    <br>
  
    <br>
    <br>

    <div ng-repeat="dealer in dealers">

      {{dealer.Store_Name}}
      <br>{{dealer.S_Email_id}}
      <br>{{dealer.Day}}
      <br>
      <input type="button" value="order" ng-click="isOpen(dealer.Day)"/>
          
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, try including and using Moment JS. http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-before/ Has some nice features for comparing and manipulating dates.

Comment: pls help me out i m trying since 3 days.pls add jsfiddle for me

Answer (score 0):

First, you are setting the shops opening times to the year 1900

```
var times = dealerSchedule[Object.keys(dealerSchedule)[now.getDay() - 1]].replace(/(\d\d\:\d\d)(AM|PM)/g, '1/1/1900 $1 $2').split(" - ");
```

Then you are getting todays date

```
var nowTime = new Date(ntime);
```

And you are checking if today's date is between two times in 1900.

```
var response = (times == "Leave" ? "Leave" : (nowTime >= new Date(times[0]) && nowTime <= new Date(times[1]) ? "Open Now" : "Closed Now"));
```

Bottom line is that you are comparing dates, when you want to be comparing times instead.